# how to validate image from form validation library codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am trying to validate an image from my form validation's extended class in codeigniter but it is not working

controller

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
}

public function add_photo() { 

 $this->form_validation->set_rules('pic','Photo','validate_image['.$_FILES['pic'].']');


  if($this->form_validation->run()) {
   //some further coding
  }
}
```

in my library

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

        public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_CI = &get_instance();
    }

public function validate_image($image = NULL) {
        print_r($image);
        $file_name      =   $image['name'];

        $allowed_ext    =   array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp');
        $ext                =   strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));

        $allowed_file_types =   array('image/jpeg','image/jpg','image/gif','image/png');
        $file_type              =   $image['type'];

        if(!in_array($ext, $allowed_ext) && !in_array($file_type, $allowed_file_types)) {
            $this->_CI->form_validation->set_message('validate_image', 'This file type is not allowed');
            return false;
        }

        if($image['size'] > 2097152) {
            $this->_CI->form_validation->set_message('validate_image', 'File size Exeeds');
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }


}
```

any suggestion and help will be appriciated thanks.

Comment: Easier way of getting the extension: `$ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Answer (score 5):

It will not work in `form validation` try it like,

```
function validate_image(){
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']    = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
    {
        $this->validation->set_message('userfile',$this->upload->display_errors());
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Refer [this](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/74624/)

Comment: rohan what is userfile

Comment: `userfile` is the `name` of your `file element`

Comment: yes I have seen but I dont what to use file uploading class in that I just want to validate image and want to set message from a library like I am trying to do it.

Comment: hi @RohanKumar , my question is that what if we have to upload multiple images. If i upload any non image file between the imges then codeigniter gives error that's perfect but it also upload some of the files. how to prevent that.

Comment: In that case you need to make a validate_image_callback in which you have to run a loop for each image extension and if a image has an invalid extension then it will return error(FALSE), so the form validation will return false.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way:
Controller:

```php
public function add_photo() { 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_image','Product Image','callback_validate_image');
    if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
        $this->add($category_id);    
    }else{
        //your logic here
    }
}
```

Callback Validation Method:

```php
public function validate_image() {
    $config = array(
        'allowed_types'=>'jpg|png',
        'upload_path'=> realpath(APPPATH . '../assets/img'),
        'max_size'=>1
        );
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('product_image'))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_image',$this->upload->display_errors());
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

`APPPATH` will give you the path to the application folder of codeigniter.
`realpath()` will give you the actual path without the `../`